# “Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH” error while running the Calabash test on iOS

Tags: ios, ruby, calabash, calabash-ios

I’m new to the **Calabash iOS** automated testing. I have installed **“Xcode 4.2”, “Ruby version 2.0.0p643” and “calabash-cucumber gem”** on Snow Leopard (version 10.6.8)

I ran the command **“calabash-ios setup”** and created a target (test-cal target) for my test iOS project. With this command, CFNetwork.framework and calabash.framework are added to the test-cal target.

After that, I ran **“calabash-ios gen”** in terminal and created a subdirectory called features and manually added features subdirectory to test-cal target.

I wrote a test script in **“sample.feature”** file under the features folder and then executed the cucumber command in terminal to test the script.

After running the command it is giving me following error:

```
Scenario: Sample test                          # features/sample.feature:3

 Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH.
  Have you built your app for simulator?

Searched dir: /Users/octaneconference/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-frkimcejhwemmaaapwknwfwvhnmb

Please build your app from Xcode

You should build the -cal target.

  Alternatively, specify APP_BUNDLE_PATH in features/support/01_launch.rb
  This should point to the location of your built app linked with calabash.
   (RuntimeError)

  ./features/support/01_launch.rb:29:in `Before'
    Given the app has launched                   # features/steps/sample_steps.rb:1
    And then the Sound Enable screen will appear # features/sample.feature:5
    When click on "NO" button                    # features/sample.feature:6
    Then Menu screen will appear in the screen   # features/sample.feature:7
    Then take a picture                          # features/sample.feature:8

Failing Scenarios:

cucumber features/sample.feature:3 # Scenario: Sample test

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 skipped, 4 undefined)
0m0.965s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^then the Sound Enable screen will appear$/)
do

pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^click on "([^"]*)" button$/) do |arg1|

  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^Menu screen will appear in the screen$/) 

do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

end

Then(/^take a picture$/) do

pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

end
```

I’d appreciate any suggestions/thoughts regarding fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, please ensure that you are using at least OSX Yosemite or later, Xcode 6 or later (preferably >= 7), and please ensure you have the latest calabash-cucumber gem (at the time of writing, 0.17.0). You can verify this by running

```
calabash-ios version
```

Secondly, from where are you running the `cucumber` command? If you are trying to get a test to run on a simulator from an xcode project, you'll need to be in the same directory as `<app_name>.xcodeproj` . As the error message suggests, you'll also need to make sure you've actually built the project for the simulator prior to running.

If you are trying to run the test on a simulator app bundle (a folder with a .app extension), then you can instead run:

```
APP_BUNDLE_PATH=/path/to/appname.app DEVICE_TARGET="<UUID>" cucumber
```

(you can find the uuids of your simulators by running `instruments -w devices` )

For what it's worth, I'd also recommend checking out the [calabash-sandbox](https://github.com/calabash/install/blob/master/README.md) for a simplified ruby setup.